# Object Instantiation returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, instantiation, argumentexception

For some reason, when attempting to instantiate this particular Game Object, I get an

> ArgumentException: the object you want to instantiate is null.

I have the particular prefab for the model I'm using in my folder labeled resources, so I have no idea why I'm getting this particular error.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using TMPro;

public class Spawnpoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int spawnGroup;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool inUse = false;

    public GameObject Spawn(NPCManager.NPC_ENUM typeID)
    {
        string prefabName = NPCManager.Instance().getPrefabName(typeID);

        GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(prefabName));

        if (go == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("cannot find refab \"Models/" + prefabName + "\"");
            return null;
        }

        go.SetActive(false);

        go.transform.position = transform.position;
        go.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
        float scale = NPCManager.Instance().getScale(typeID);
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);

        TextMeshProUGUI nameText = go.transform.FindDeepChild("BillboardText").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        nameText.text = NPCManager.Instance().getName(typeID);

        AIController.MyAIController ctrl = go.GetComponent<AIController.MyAIController>();
        ctrl.destination = go.transform.position;
        go.SetActive(true);

        return go;
    }
}
```

[Here is what my particular Resources file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0yri.png)

I feel like I've tried everything to fix this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this:
`GameObject go= Instantiate(Resources.Load(prefabName, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;` ?

Comment: If type is not the problem, then your path is incorrect, there is no third option, as you can see from here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Comment: @nemanja228 is there any way to ensure that the path is going to my resources folder under my assets tab? There's no other folder inside my resource folder. Im rather new to unity and C# haha.

Comment: As of right now, whenever i run my editor to test the code,  GameObject go= Instantiate(Resources.Load(prefabName, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject; , it freezes.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: How do I debug code like this without running it through unity?

Comment: You debug it while running in Unity, by attaching to process. Look up debugging for your editor (Visual Studio or another one if you don't use it). Put the breakpoint on that line and you will solve it in minutes.

Comment: By the way, it isn't `Instantiate` that's "returning null," but `Resources.Load(prefabName)` that's returning null. Whatever string you passed in does not correspond to a prefab and you haven't told us what that string is.